# Swift 3 - Cannot call value of non-function type 'XCUIElement'

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, coded-ui-tests, swift3

I am trying to simplify my UITest code.  At this time I have hundreds of lines of code for checking up to eight table rows each with three text fields.  This will not only reduce the number of lines of code that I have, but it will reduce the erros that are caused by the copy/paste/edit process.

I am getting a "Cannot call value of non-function type 'XCUIElement'" error on the three lines in the checkRow function.

If I replace the 'thisRow' variable in the three lines with an integer, the code will compile.

Here is the before and after.

```
func testAkcCh() {
    navConfig.tap()
    pickCD.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "4")
    pickCB.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "5")
    pickSD.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "3")
    pickSB.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "2")
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.count == 8)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts["Best of Breed"].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts[p5].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts[d13].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 1).staticTexts["Best of Opposite Sex"].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 1).staticTexts[p5].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 1).staticTexts[d06].exists)
}
```

into

```
func checkRow(thisRow: Int, thisAward: String, thisPoints: String, thisDefeated: String) {
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: thisRow).staticTexts[thisAward].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: thisRow).staticTexts[thisPoints].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: thisRow).staticTexts[thisDefeated].exists)
}

func testAkcCh() {
    navConfig.tap()
    pickCD.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "4")
    pickCB.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "5")
    pickSD.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "3")
    pickSB.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "2")
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.count == 8)
    checkRow(0, "Best of Breed", p5, d13)
    checkRow(1, "Best of Opposite Sex", p5, d06)
}
```

This compiles, but defeated most of the benefit...

```
func checkRow(thisRow: Int, thisAward: String, thisPoints: String, thisDefeated: String) {
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts[thisAward].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts[thisPoints].exists)
    XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts[thisDefeated].exists)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function signature of the `element(...` function looks like:

```
func element(boundBy index: UInt) -> XCUIElement
```

The compiler is interpreting your `0` literal as the appropriate type for the context, which when passed directly is `UInt`. However, when passing 0 into `checkRow`, it interprets it as an `Int` since that is the type you specified for `thisRow`.

My guess is that you need to change the type of your `thisRow` parameter to `UInt`:

```
func checkRow(thisRow: UInt, thisAward: String, thisPoints: String, thisDefeated: String) {
```

---

Or alternatively, convert `thisRow` to `UInt` like:

```
XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: UInt(thisRow)).staticTexts[thisAward].exists)
```

Comment: Just updated to Swift 4 and started getting the same error again with no changes to the code.  I had to remove the Uint(xxx).

XCTAssertFalse(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: thisRow).exists)

Comment: Seems like apple changed the signature from `UInt` to `Int` with Swift 4. `func element(boundBy index: Int) -> XCUIElement`